# How can I scale the width of container in css3

Tags: css

How can I scale an element to occupy full width and height of browser using css3 transitions? I can use scale function. But how can I calculate the factor I should use for scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an example for webkit (Chrome, Safari)

http://jsfiddle.net/dM8zL/

```
#expandme {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;        
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
}
#expandme:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  position: fixed;  
 -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;     
}
```

Comment: hmm, quicker and nicer than mine... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like what you wanted?
http://jsfiddle.net/RcXfN/4/

Answer (score 0):

Scaling does not require css3 you can just use simple % for width and height.